# Conditional SQL Select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table below.

```
Name          Product
---------------------
Value          2002
HigherLimit    *
HigherLimit    2002
LowerLimit     *
```

I need a select statement to return distinct(Name) with the following condition.

If a Product is 2002 then return '2002' else return '*'

Here is the expected result

```
Name          Product
---------------------
Value          2002
HigherLimit    2002
LowerLimit     *
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks 
Niju

Comment: Is it distinct name and product, if not is it if any of the names have a product use 2002, if not use *? And what is your DB server?

Comment: what rdbms you are using? MySQL? SQLServer? Oracle? etc....

Comment: Only distinct name, distinct product is inserted per name. IT is SQL 2008 R2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `2002` will evaluate as greater than `*`, you can simply use a `MAX()` aggregate grouped by `Name`:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  MAX(Product) AS Product
FROM yourtable
/* WHERE Product IN ('2002', '*') -- if necessary */
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Product DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8da48/2

However, if your real table has more values than just  `2002` or `*`, and you want to return the 2002 values rather than the greatest number, use a `CASE` to separate out the value you want (2002) and return all others as `*`. The `MAX()` aggregate is applied in the same way though:

```
SELECT
  Name,
  /* Force *all* values not 2002 to be `*` */
  MAX(CASE WHEN Product = '2002' THEN Product ELSE '*' END) AS Product
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Product DESC
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f03af/2